# MySQL complaining about multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have the following logic in a mysql stored proc:

```
SET @UserId = (
Select userid
FROM tickets
where ticketid = ticketID
);
```

It's giving me an error:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

I removed the set around it and just ran the query:

```
Select userid
FROM tickets
where ticketid = ticketID;
```

I get back 1 record, why is it complaining that I have more than 1 row? ticketid is the primary key on that table as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the predicate in the WHERE clause

```
 ticketid = ticketID
```

would evaluate to TRUE for all non-null values of ticketid.

Essentially equivalent to specifying

```
 ticketid IS NOT NULL
```

And if `ticketid` is the PRIMARY KEY, then every row in the table would satisfy that condition.

---

I'm just guessing here. I suspect you have declared a variable named `ticketID` and are expecting MySQL to differentiate between `ticketid` being a reference to a column, and `ticketID` being a reference to a variable. But that doesn't happen.  If there is a procedure variable named `ticketID` (that's declared in scope of a SQL statement), MySQL takes a reference to `ticketid` as a reference to the variable. So, again, every row in the table will be returned if `ticketid` variable has a non-null value.

---

From the MySQL Reference Manual:

> A local variable should not have the same name as a table column. If an SQL statement, such as a SELECT ... INTO statement, contains a reference to a column and a declared local variable with the same name, MySQL currently interprets a reference to that name as the name of a variable.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/local-variable-scope.html

---

If that's the issue (again, I'm just guessing there) a workaround is to **qualify** references to the columns with the table name or table alias.

A lot of developers also name their variables with a prefix, or some other convention, which makes it easier for the reader to distinguish variable names from column names, by reducing ambiguity.

For example:

```
  DECLARE lv_ticketid INT; 

  SET @UserId = ( SELECT t.userid FROM tickets t WHERE t.ticketid = lv_ticketid );
```

And where we know that only one row will be returned, we can also add a LIMIT 1 to the query, depending on whether we want an error thrown when there is more than one row returned.

```
  SET @UserId = ( SELECT t.userid
                   FROM tickets t
                  WHERE t.ticketid = lv_ticketid 
                  ORDER BY t.userid ASC
                  LIMIT 1 
                );
```

Comment: That's exactly what it was, it was having a problem differentiating the field and variable "ticketId"

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is case-insensitive when it comes to column names and keywords. When you say `where ticketid = ticketID` it thinks you're just saying the value of column `ticketid` is the same as itself, which will always be true. Try changing the variable to something else.